# C# API POST similar to CURL

Tags: c#, api, curl, post, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to use the vultr.com API that utilizes CURL.  I have successfully completed a POST call to their API with several different calls, but one in particular will not work.  Here is their documentation on the API https://www.vultr.com/api/ .

I am able to get their server/create  and firewall/rule_create to work properly with pretty much the same exact code, but it will not work for their server/reboot command.  Now here is code for a post to their API that I have successfully gotten to work.

```
public static void AddIpToFirewall(string ip,string fireWallGroupId)
{
    string Data = "FIREWALLGROUPID=" + fireWallGroupId + "&direction=in&ip_type=v4&protocol=tcp&subnet=" + ip + "&subnet_size=32&port=80";
    string Reponse = String.Empty;
    StreamWriter Sw = null;
    StreamReader Sr = null;
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest Req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.vultr.com/v1/firewall/rule_create");
        Req.Method = "POST";
        Req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        Req.ContentLength = Data.Length;
        Req.Headers.Add(ApiKey);
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(Req.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            sw.Write(Data);
        }
        Sr = new
        StreamReader(((HttpWebResponse)Req.GetResponse()).GetResponseStream());
        Reponse = Sr.ReadToEnd();
        Sr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (Sw != null)
            Sw.Close();
        if (Sr != null)
            Sr.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + "\r\n\r\n'error with vultr...");
    }
}
```

Now here is the code that will not work.  It's pretty much identical to the firewall POST command.

```
public static void RebootCommand(string subId)
{
    string Data = "SUBID=" + subId;
    string Reponse = String.Empty;
    StreamWriter Sw = null;
    StreamReader Sr = null;
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest Req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.vultr.com/v1/server/reboot");
        Req.Method = "POST";
        Req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        Req.ContentLength = Data.Length;
        Req.Headers.Add(ApiKey);
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(Req.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            sw.Write(Data);
        }
        Sr = new
        StreamReader(((HttpWebResponse)Req.GetResponse()).GetResponseStream());
        Reponse = Sr.ReadToEnd();
        Sr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (Sw != null)
            Sw.Close();
        if (Sr != null)
            Sr.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + " error with vultr...");
    }
}
```

It does not receive an error, but fails to reboot the VM.  I've contacted their support and they say that their reboot command is working without any issues.  Is there anyone out there that has had this issue before?  Thanks.

Comment: Is anything written to the console when this executes?

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `subId`? Also, the documentation claims that API Key is required, but your code doesn't appear to set it. https://www.vultr.com/api/

Comment: How do you confirm that VM is not restarting? Did you check the status of the VM? Restarting might take some time it won't be done in fraction of a second.

Comment: I am able to get the exact value of subId without any issues using a get.  During debugging I pause and confirm it's correct.  The API key is passed by a constant variable.  It is also correct as it works perfectly fine with other calls.  I confirm that the VM is not restarting by their dashboard and also by making a direct console connection.  It never restarts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  With all of the other POST requests that I have done from their API the line Req.ContentLength = Data.Length was required.  But for whatever reason that line had to be removed to get the reboot command to work.